# Calling WCF web service through URL

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I'm trying to access the service that I've hosted in "IIS" Windows 2012 Server, an error message occurs as:
[image: Error]

while service is opening normally when you access the link directly:
[image: Good]

http://localhost:5796/Service1.svc ==> Opening
http://localhost:5796/Service1.svc/GetInfo?id=5 ==> error occurs

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the server logs?

Comment: Try adding some tracing and look for the error: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: we can not say anything until we see the actual error.

Comment: Actually I don't now where to see the server logs.

Note that when I'm trying to access it from localhost without hosting it on IIS it works, while if I've tried it on IIS its not reachable so I'm sure there's no error in code!

Kindly help me.

Comment: Then there's something different in **how** you are hosting it.  Can you provide the config files for both the IIS and non-IIS hosted instances?

Comment: Find the below picutres of my hosted XML which is the same as non hosted one:
http://s16.postimg.org/jzvw6zqkl/image.png
http://s27.postimg.org/xnz2todcj/image.png

Help me please!